# How to display multiple unicode text files in non-unicode program

Tags: windows, unicode

OS:WinXP

Say I got some files in Chinese and some files in Korean. And in windows 'Region and Language Options', I set language for non-unicode program = Chinese. Is there any way that I can read some Korean text file in text editor easily without using Microsoft Word?

I need an environment that can support multiple unicode easily, I need to read Chinese, Japanese, Korean in text editor (Ultraeditor, notepad++) and terminal clients like SecureCRT. Please advise, thanks.

Another quick question is how does Word recognize which language in the text file? Is there any information in the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question you could try Microsoft AppLocale utility

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=8C4E8E0D-45D1-4D9B-B7C0-8430C1AC89AB&displaylang=en

I'm not Word user, but I'd guess that when a document is saved with a given encoding, the codepage for the language is stored as part of the document metadata.

Answer (score 1):

> Say I got some files in Chinese and
>   some files in Korean. And in windows
>   'Region and Language Options', I set
>   language for non-unicode program =
>   Chinese. Is there any way that I can
>   read some Korean text file in text
>   editor easily without using Microsoft
>   Word?

Yes, you need to use an editor that supports multiple encodings. Most full-featured editors (notepad++, (g)vim, etc.) support this. Usually, you need to tell the editor which encoding the text file has (because this information is not in the file itself), though sometimes the editor can guess it for you. E.g. in Notepad++ and gvim there are menu/config settings for choosing the encoding.

> I need to read Chinese, Japanese,
>   Korean in text editor (Ultraeditor,
>   notepad++) and terminal clients like
>   SecureCRT. Please advise, thanks.

For reading in text editors, see above. As to "SecureCRT": I assume you mean the file is on a remote server which you access via SecureCRT. Then you need to use an editor on the remote system that supports the file's encoding.

> Another quick question is how does
>   Word recognize which language in the
>   text file? Is there any information in
>   the text

For plain text files, in general you cannot tell the encoding. However, you can guess (mostly based on byte frequency); this is probably what Word does.

Comment: I choose the encoding as Korean in Notepad++ but only see squares. Do I need to install Korean font and set the font in notepad++ as well? What are missing?

Comment: Hard to tell without additional info. But you definitely need a Korean font, if you don't already have one.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is any palin at all that support multiple encoding.

Notepad ++ cannot display multiple encoded data in the same file.

But it is very much possible that you can use different language in the same text file. But it must have to be same encoding.

As Example
日本 this is in japanese
বাংলাদেশ this is bengali.
한국 (i think this is korean)

But all used same encoding (UTF-8 in this case)

And Of course the browser you are using cannot display two encoding same time.

if you have development idea. You can try simple test on encoding issue. try to print two different encoded data in the same page. you will get garbage output.

But if you might get some pretty interesting issue where it will seems that you are getting data in different encoding... as example

say you have two different text file with two different encoding. 
1. UTF-8
2. SHIFT-JIS

both containing Japanese text. If you copy some text from one text file and paste it to other you will see a successful pasting. you must ask that they are different encoding how come they are getting pasted in the same text file?

the answer is when you copy some text it get copied in **UNICODE** and also pasted as unicode(with my little programming knowledge all text that is displayed on windows are in unicode. If you dont convert text to Unicode you cannot print them properly). But when user save the file, it get saved in its proper encoding....................